# Find RDD[(T, U)] elements that have key in RDD[T]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given

```
val as: RDD[(T, U)]
val bs: RDD[T]
```

I would like to filter `as` to find the elements with keys present `bs`.

One approach is

```
val intermediateAndOtherwiseUnnessaryPair = bs.map(b => b -> b)
bs.join(as).values
```

But the mapping on `bs` is unfortunate. Is there a more direct method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the mapping less unnecessary by doing:

```
val intermediateAndOtherwiseUnnessaryPair = bs.map(b => (b, 1))
```

Also, co-partitioning before joining helps a lot:

```
val intermediateAndOtherwiseUnnessaryPair = bs.map(b => (b, 1)).paritionBy(new HashPartitioner(NUM_PARTITIONS))

bs.paritionBy(new HashPartitioner(NUM_PARTITIONS)).join(as).values
```

Co partitioned RDDs will not be shuffled at runtime, and thus you'll see a significant performance boost.

Broadcasting may not work if `bs` is too big (more precisely, has a large number of unique values), you may also want to increase `driver.maxResultsize`.

Comment: do you have by any change benchmarks for this? I mean using partitionBy vs not using it? How I see it we will still get shuffles on both `as` and `bs` when they are created.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk True, a shuffle is unavoidable. However, I have seen in practice that doing a pre partitioning avoids all the "FetchFailedExceptions", which I reckon are caused by memory issues. Shooting in the dark, but it feels that it is too much work to move around both the RDDs AND join, pre-partitioning makes it easier on the framework. Again, this is all from experience, no benchmarks.

Comment: FetchFailedException can happen due to many reasons such as executors not responding or incorrectly setting the number of partitions by yourself (or by default by Spark) but it really depends on the use case. If you set too many partitions you'll actually get more shuffles. I'd say this is premature optimisation which might backfire in many cases.

Comment: I see. However, I can reproduce the scenario of `join` not working without co partitioning first on the datasets I work on (~1T). Also, interesting point about fetchfailed caused by incorrect number of partitions. Why would that happen? In my experience, increasing the number of partitions (~5 * number of cores) has usually helped, decreasing the number of partitions has never been helpful. But I guess spark has too many knobs and handles to make general statements.

Comment: I was asking myself the same question actually, to me it looks like chaining a partition and a join cause the data to shuffle twice which should be much slower than joining alone, unless the join operation takes a huge increase in performance for a partitioned RDD, couldn't find any info on this though.

Comment: @EndeNeu No, if RDDs are already partitioned, shuffling doesn't happen twice: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html

Comment: @axiom but your `paritionBy` causes a shuffle anyway so we're back at square one.... Shuffle on join can be only avoided if from the start both RDDs have the same partitioner (i.e. their lineage points to the same parent RDD somewhere and no reshuffles were made)

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk As I've said, from my experience, *shuffling that happens with the join* hurts the performance, sometimes to the point of killing of the application due to memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

The only two (or at least the only ones I am aware of) popular and generic ways to filter one `RDD` using a second `RDD` are:

1) `join` which you are already doing - in this case I wouldn't worry about the unnecessary intermediate `RDD` that much though, `map()` is a narrow transformation and won't introduce that much overhead. The `join()` itself will most probably be slow, though, as it's a wide transformation (requires shuffles)

2) collecting the `bs` on the driver and making it a broadcast variable which then will be used in `as.filter()`

```
val collected = sc.broadcast(bs.collect().toSet)
as.filter(el => collected.value.contains(el))
```

You need to do this as Spark doesn't support nesting `RDDs` inside methods called on `RDD`.